# Lastest month data from every ID in DAX

Tags: sql-server, ssas, dax, msbi

I am new to **Powerbi** and **DAX**, I need to retrieve the last month data by partition by ID in the measure in DAX query. Which would be the best way to achieve this?.

[image: My data format].

Comment: i want to add new column with this data

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:

```
LatestMonth = CALCULATE(MAX(TableName[Month]),
                  ALLEXCEPT(TableName, TableName[ID]))
```

Another option is this:

```
LatestMonth = CALCULATE(MAX(TableName[Month]),
                  FILTER(TableName,
                      TableName[ID] = EARLIER(TableName[ID])))
```

Comment: i want amount to be display as a output for max month

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say. What is the issue with what I suggested?